# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteQuery in unit test that worked yesterday

Tags: android-studio, android-unit-testing

The answer to this question is not "Android unit tests cannot access Android stack modules such as the Room database because on your desktop they are all stubbed out."

I had a bunch of unit tests that tested static methods that happened to be inside a Dao class - call it `FooDao`. They all passed for a year until today, when they stopped passing when the Android Studio editor calls them. They still pass when the command line tests call them, but the editor reports:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteQuery
```

This happens when the unit test gets to `FooDao.innocentStaticMethod()`. Like I said, accessing the `FooDao` class without invoking any of its real Room methods formerly worked in unit tests.

The long-term fix is to refactor my code so `FooDao` only contains real Room calls. But why did Android Studio's test runner suddenly stop working? The version is Android Studio 4.2 RC 1, built on March 23, 2021. And `targetSdkVersion 30`.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from `androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6` and compiler to `2.3.0` did it, on April 22th.

In app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6'
```

So while I leave a band-aid on the problem until the next time we need to upgrade my mighty `FooDao`, could someone ping Android central about this? ktx